# JQuery "click" event won't fire when triggered in dev console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that has some dynamic text that opens a window to another page when clicked.  It works when I click on the text in my page, but if I try to trigger the click event itself (I am working in the dev console testing new features), it doesn't trigger.  Here is the simplified code I have written:

```
var idOfLoadedText = response.getText;

$("#" + idOfLoadedText).click(function() {
    window.open('https://mtLink.com');
    return false;
});
```

Very simple, and it works as intended in the site.  However, if I go to the dev console and type in:

```
$("#" + idOfLoadedText).click();
```

It doesn't open the window.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**  You are all going to hate me....I guess my system had a reset recently, and the pop-ups were being blocked.

Comment: Are you sure `idOfLoadedText` is defined and valid?

Comment: @rnevius yeah, I was just using the variable to not be confusing.  I am testing with the specific returned string displayed in the element, so I am not using variables when I try to trigger the click myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idOfLoadedText` is likely not globally accessible. You *could* define it on `window`, and do something like....

```
window.idOfLoadedText = 'hoorah' // -- or response.getText;
```

---

```
$('#' + window.idOfLoadedText).click(); // -- $('#hoorah').click()
```

but, this is likely not ideal. You'll want this somewhere globally accessable to run it in your console, perhaps somewhere better than the root of `window`. If you just want to see it working, place it on `window` and go for it

---

Check this [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/50kbr0tx/1/). Open dev tools, click **top frame** => **(result.jshell.net/)** and run `$('#' + window.idOfLoadedText).click()` in your console

Comment: Sorry, I must not have been clear in my question.  I even went to the page, found an example of the text already loaded, and grabbed that specific id to test it, and nothing.  So for example, I did `$("#actualID").click()`  Like I said, it works in the page by clicking on the text, but trying to trigger it from JQuery, or dev console, does not work.

Comment: `$("#actualID").click()` should work in your console

Comment: haha, it should, but no event is being triggered :)  Does the fact that this is a dynamic element have anything to do with this?  I can't show the whole application (work related and stuff), but it is text in a field of a table, which I am creating the HTML for in a JQuery file when I retrieve the info from a DB

Comment: Also, `'#actualID'` assumes your event handler is defined as `$('#actualID').click(function() { [...] })`

Comment: ....as shamed as I am to say it...my system restarted, and the pop-up blocker was re-enabled.  Thanks for the help though!  I'm gonna sulk in the dumb corner for a while